# How to read custom JWT claims into Go struct?

Tags: go, jwt

I create a JWT token with this code

```
func GenerateUserToken(user model.User) (string, error) {
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)
    claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    claims["iss"] = ISS
    claims["func"] = "user"
    claims["userId"] = user.UserId
    claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * tokenLifetime).Unix()
    claims["identities"] = user.Identities
    claims["admin"] = user.Admin
    st, err := token.SignedString(Secret)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return st, nil
}
```

Then I verify and get claims with this code

```
// bearerToken should be "Bearer <JWT>"
func VerifyUserToken(bearerToken string) (*model.UserClaims, bool) {
    strArr := strings.Split(bearerToken, " ")
    if len(strArr) != 2 || strArr[0] != "Bearer" {
        return nil, false
    }
    claims, ok := VerifyToken(strArr[1])
    if ok && claims.Func != "user" {
        return nil, false
    }

    return claims, ok
}

func VerifyToken(tokenStr string) (*model.UserClaims, bool) {
    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenStr, &model.UserClaims{}, func (token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method")
        }
        return Secret, nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, false
    }
    var ok bool
    var claims *model.UserClaims
    claims, ok = token.Claims.(*model.UserClaims)
    fmt.Println(claims.Admin)
    return claims, ok && token.Valid
}
```

My user struct definition

```
type User struct {
    UserId string `json:"userId"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
    Identities []IdentityNoPii `json:"identities"`
    Created uint64 `json:"created"`
    Admin bool `json:"admin"`
}

type UserClaims struct {
    User
    jwt.StandardClaims
    Func string `json:"func"`
    Sub string `json:"sub"`
}
```

I create a token where the `Admin` field of the user/token is true. I can verify that this is the case on jwt.io. However, when I pass the token string into my `VerifyUserToken()` function, Admin is consistently false. How can I ensure all fields are read correctly?

Comment: Hi, your code is correct and the `Admin` is true. See [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/sfASWccg33a).

Comment: Hmm, okay thanks. It must be getting reset somewhere else or I am using the wrong value. I will investigate some more.